# NodeJS Request POST Iconv

Tags: javascript, node.js, iconv

I tried to use request with iconv-lite,
but i've got some problems.

I know `Iconv-lite` encode method throws a `Buffer`

Here is some Korean Text `테스트` `(UTF-8)`
I want to covert `EUC-KR`.

```
var str = "테스트";
var sms = iconv.encode(new Buffer(str), 'euc-kr');
request.post({
    uri: 'http://some_http_server/',
    form: { // Encoding of form data should be EUC-KR.
        "sms": sms,
        "date": "0"
    }
}, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
        callback(null);
    }
});
```

but `Request` does not send a `EUC-KR` encoding strings.
I know NodeJS. when change to string type that has only `UTF-8` encoding

I don't understand what should i do. because my skill is not good.
somebody help with me?

Comment: What encoding does Request actually send?

Comment: I want to send `EUC-KR` encoding to request server. It is only get `EUC-KR`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find out the euc-kr numerical representation of each character in `테스트`. (try searching: "code point", "code unit", "character code")

Encoding the utf8 representation as euc-kr strips bytes creating a different string.

```
// ** Not the actual values **
var numericalValues = new Buffer([0x2134, 0x1231, 0x3413]);
var form = { sms: sms, data: '0' };
```

There's most likely an algorithm to convert utf8 korean characters to euc-kr but there's not many resources on it. At least of what I can find and read.

I hope you're able to accomplish what you want to do. When you found a way post it up here, I'd be interested seeing the solution.

Comment: Oh, then send the encoded data like you are. It's up to the receiver of the post to interpret the data. Maybe add a headers field to your form and specify `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=euc-kr'`

Comment: Encoding Failed. request server return `占쏙옙` not a `테스트` string. when encoding failure on UTF-8 to EUC-KR, it return`占쏙옙`

Comment: I see what's going on. You want to send the exact string `테스트`, but when converted to _euc-kr_ from _utf8_ it will be different string because euc-kr is a 2 byte encoding. I'll change answer

Comment: i can't understand how to use fully code.
also i can get more information about euc-kr `code point`.